# Fill in Word template and save as pdf using openxml and openoffice

Tags: c#, openxml, openoffice.org

I am trying to fill a word document with data from an XML. I am using openXML to fill the document, which works great and save it as .docx. The thing is I have to open Word and save the document as an .odt and then use the OpenOffice SDK to open the .docx and save it as a pdf. When I don't save the .docx as .odt, the formatting is off.

What I need to be able to do is be able to either convert the .docx to .odt or save it originally as .odt.

Here is what I have right now:

```
    static void Main()
        {

            string documentText;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); // Create an XML document object
            xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Cache\\MMcache.xml"); // Load the XML document from the specified file



            XmlNodeList PatientFirst = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("PatientFirst");

            XmlNodeList PatientSignatureImg = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("PatientSignatureImg");






            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Cache\\TransportationRunReporttemplate.docx");
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                    {
                        documentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }





                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        writer.Write(documentText);
                    }

                }
                // Save the file with the new name
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Cache\\MYFINISHEDTEMPLATE.docx", stream.ToArray());
            }




        }

        private static void AddPicture(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("C:\\Cache\\MYFINISHEDTEMPLATE.docx", true))
            {
                //Bitmap image = new Bitmap("C:\\Cache\\scribus.jpg");
                SdtElement controlBlock = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                    .Descendants<SdtElement>()
                        .Where
                        (r =>
                            r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Signature"
                        ).SingleOrDefault();
                // Find the Blip element of the content control.
                A.Blip blip = controlBlock.Descendants<A.Blip>().FirstOrDefault();
                ImagePart imagePart = doc.MainDocumentPart
        .AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                }
                blip.Embed = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);

               /* DW.Inline inline = controlBlock
        .Descendants<DW.Inline>().FirstOrDefault();
                // 9525 = pixels to points
                inline.Extent.Cy = image.Size.Height * 9525;
                inline.Extent.Cx = image.Size.Width * 9525;
                PIC.Picture pic = inline
                    .Descendants<PIC.Picture>().FirstOrDefault();
                pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy
                    = image.Size.Height * 9525;
                pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx
                    = image.Size.Width * 9525;*/
            }
            ConvertToPDF(@"C:\Cache\MYFINISHEDTEMPLATE2.docx",@"C:\Cache\OpenPdf.pdf");

        }






        public static Bitmap Base64StringToBitmap(string base64String)
        {
            Bitmap bmpReturn = null;


            byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);


            memoryStream.Position = 0;


            bmpReturn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);


            memoryStream.Close();
            memoryStream = null;
            byteBuffer = null;


            return bmpReturn;
        }
     public static void ConvertToPDF(string inputFile, string outputFile)
        {
            if (ConvertExtensionToFilterType(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(inputFile)) == null)
                throw new InvalidProgramException("Unknown file type for OpenOffice. File = " + inputFile);

            StartOpenOffice();

            //Get a ComponentContext
            var xLocalContext =
                Bootstrap.bootstrap();
            //Get MultiServiceFactory
            var xRemoteFactory =
                (XMultiServiceFactory)
                xLocalContext.getServiceManager();
            //Get a CompontLoader
            var aLoader =
                (XComponentLoader)xRemoteFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
            //Load the sourcefile

            XComponent xComponent = null;
            try
            {
                xComponent = InitDocument(aLoader,
                                          PathConverter(inputFile), "_blank");
                //Wait for loading
                while (xComponent == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                // save/export the document
                SaveDocument(xComponent, inputFile, PathConverter(outputFile));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (xComponent != null) xComponent.dispose();
            }

        }

        private static void StartOpenOffice()
        {
            var ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("soffice.exe");
            if (ps.Length != 0)
                throw new InvalidProgramException("OpenOffice not found.  Is OpenOffice installed?");
            if (ps.Length > 0)
                return;
            var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Arguments = "-headless -nofirststartwizard",
                    FileName = "soffice.exe",
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            var result = p.Start();

            if (result == false)
                throw new InvalidProgramException("OpenOffice failed to start.");
        }

        private static XComponent InitDocument(XComponentLoader aLoader, string file, string target)
        {
            var openProps = new PropertyValue[1];
            openProps[0] = new PropertyValue { Name = "Hidden", Value = new Any(true) };

            XComponent xComponent = aLoader.loadComponentFromURL(
               file, target, 0,
               openProps);

            return xComponent;
        }


        private static void SaveDocument(XComponent xComponent, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
        {
            var propertyValues = new PropertyValue[2];
            // Setting the flag for overwriting
            propertyValues[1] = new PropertyValue { Name = "Overwrite", Value = new Any(true) };
            //// Setting the filter name
            propertyValues[0] = new PropertyValue
            {
                Name = "FilterName",
                Value = new Any(ConvertExtensionToFilterType(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sourceFile)))
            };
            ((XStorable)xComponent).storeToURL(destinationFile, propertyValues);

        }


        private static string PathConverter(string file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Null or empty path passed to OpenOffice");

            return String.Format("file:///{0}", file.Replace(@"\", "/"));

        }

        public static string ConvertExtensionToFilterType(string extension)
        {
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".odt":
                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                case ".txt":
                case ".rtf":
                case ".html":
                case ".htm":
                case ".xml":                
                case ".wps":
                case ".wpd":
                    return "writer_pdf_Export";
                case ".xls":
                case ".xlsb":
                case ".ods":
                    return "calc_pdf_Export";
                case ".ppt":
                case ".pptx":
                case ".odp":
                    return "impress_pdf_Export";

                default: return null;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Just for information I cannot use anything that uses Interop because word will not be installed the machine. I am using OpenXML and OpenOffice

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try (details below):
 1) try Doc format instead of DocX
 2) switch to Libre Office and try DocX again
 2) use the odf-converter to get a better DocX -> ODT conversion.

More details...

There's something called the odf-conveter (opensource) that can convert DocX->ODT which gives you (typically) more accurate DocX->ODT than Open Office.  Take a look at odf-conveter-integrator by OONinja for pre-packaged versions.

Also, Libre Office has DocX support ahead of OpenOffice so you might get a better result simply by switching to Libre Office.

A further option is to start from Doc format rather than DocX.  In the OpenOffice world that translates much better to ODT and then to PDF.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Docxpresso](http://www.docxpresso.com) to generate your .odt directly from HTML + CSS code and avoid any conversion issue.

Docxpresso is free for non-commercial use.